# Using grid-template-columns in ReactJS, inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

Im trying to use the `CSS` grid in a `React` component, but I get an error in the first dash of `grid-template-columns`, any ideas why this happens?

```
<div style={{display:'grid', grid-template-columns: '1fr 1fr'}}>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style),

> The style attribute accepts a JavaScript object with camelCased properties rather than a CSS string.

In `React`, inline style uses `camelCase` name for `CSS` properties without `-`, like

```
<div style={{display:'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr'}}>
```